# Join and plot data with different times in 10 minute interval

Tags: mysql, r, ms-access, nstimeinterval

I have 3 tables in an Access database with the same column names (`TempDate` and `Temp`), but different time stamps. The data was collected in 10 minute intervals, but each of the recording devices had different start times. I want to merge these into one table with a single TempDate and one Temp column for each of the tables (temp1, temp2, temp3).

I need help on how to do this in either Access or R. I've started using R with MySQL code but I'm still very new at it. Thanks in advance. Ultimately I want to join this data to another dataframe with a datetime stamp from the same period of dates. I think I can manage that if someone can show me how to tell it to group by an interval. Then finally plot using ggplot

Data

```
    temp1<-data.frame(TempDate=c("2020/08/11 07:13:01","2020/08/11 07:23:01","2020/08/11 07:33:01","2020/08/11 07:43:01"),Temperature=c(1.610,-1.905,-1.905,-0.901))

temp2<-data.frame(TempDate=c("2020/08/11 07:10:01","2020/08/11 07:20:01","2020/08/11 07:30:01","2020/08/11 07:40:01"),Temperature=c(15.641,15.641,15.641,15.641))

temp3<-data.frame(TempDate=c("2020/08/11 07:19:01","2020/08/11 07:29:01","2020/08/11 07:39:01","2020/08/11 07:49:01"),Temperature=c(2.062,3.573,4.076,4.579))

> temp3 #as example
             TempDate Temperature
1 2020/08/11 07:19:01       2.062
2 2020/08/11 07:29:01       3.573
3 2020/08/11 07:39:01       4.076
4 2020/08/11 07:49:01       4.579

#what I want row 1 is temps recorded from 07:10:00-07:29:59, etc
> 
             TempDate    Temp1    Temp2   Temp3
1 2020/08/11 07:10:00    1.610    15.641   2.062
2 2020/08/11 07:20:00    -1.905   15.641   3.573
3 2020/08/11 07:30:00    -1.905   15.641   4.076
4 2020/08/11 07:40:00    -1.901   15.641   4.579
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to Ben for the great answer to get me started solving this problem. In asking another question, `floor_date` was suggested. This code worked better for my data than the cut function by @Ben.  When using cut I would get times ending in 9 (12:19) instead of 0 (12:10). I also tried `TempDate+60` within the cut function, but then some dates would get a time in the next 10 minute interval. The below code was more accurate.

```
library(lubridate)    
tempdata<-bind_rows(burrow=burrow,shade=shade,sun=sun,.id='Series') %>%
       mutate(TempDate = as.POSIXct(TempDate, tz="UTC"),
         TimeStamp = floor_date(TempDate, unit='10 mins'),
         TimeStamp = as.POSIXct(TimeStamp, tz="UTC")) %>%
       filter(TimeStamp > as.POSIXct("2020-08-12 13:29:00", tz="UTC")) %>%
       select(Series, Temperature,TimeStamp) %>%
       arrange(TimeStamp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R you could do the following, using `tidyverse` approach.

First, you can use `bind_rows` to put all your data frames together, and add a `source` column with the name of data frame those temperatures came from, or destination column in final result.

Then, make sure your `TempDate` is `POSIXct`. You can use `cut` to put your datetimes into 10 minute intervals.

At this point, I would consider leaving the result as is for plotting with `ggplot2`. It's often preferable to leave in "long" format instead of "wide". However, if you want it in "wide" format, then you can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(temp1 = temp1, temp2 = temp2, temp3 = temp3, .id = 'source') %>%
  mutate(TempDate = as.POSIXct(TempDate),
         NewTempDate = cut(TempDate, breaks = "10 min")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = NewTempDate, names_from = source, values_from = Temperature)
```

**Output**

```
  NewTempDate          temp1 temp2 temp3
  <fct>                <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-08-11 07:10:00  1.61   15.6  2.06
2 2020-08-11 07:20:00 -1.90   15.6  3.57
3 2020-08-11 07:30:00 -1.90   15.6  4.08
4 2020-08-11 07:40:00 -0.901  15.6  4.58
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for this. I wanted a graph with each temp being a different line. Your recommendation for long data then means I can just add a new column to each data frame for the type of temperature then bind them together. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In Access (VBA), you can round the times down like this:

```vb
texttime = "2020/08/11 07:19:01"
truetime = DateValue(texttime) + TimeSerial(Hour(CDate(texttime)), (Minute(CDate(texttime)) \ 10) * 10, 0)

' Result:
' 2020-11-08 07:10:00
```

However, how to implement this in **R**, I don't know.